# Matplotlib displaying axes but not datapoints

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to plot a velocity profile, with the following code. The axes are plotted, however no data points are plotted.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n = 0.4
k = 53
d = 0.000264
r = 0.000132
p = 15000
u = (n/n+1)*(p*1/2*k)**(1/n)*(d**((n+1)/n) - r**((n+1)/n))
plt.plot(u)
```

Graph produced:
[image: Graph produced]

Comment: u contains a single number. It won’t be shown the way you plotted. Try using a marker plt.plot(u, ‘o’) to visualize it. plt.plot by default uses a line for which you need at least two points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, note that `(p*1/2*k)` is a very confusing way to write a multiplication. In (about all) programming languages, the multiplications and divisions are done left to right, so, `(p*1/2*k)` equals `(p*k/2)` while perhaps you meant `(p/(2*k))`.

When [plotting a 2D graph](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/), you have to think what you want in the `x` direction, and what in the `y` direction. As you only give an `x`, there is nothing to plot. Also, `plot` default want to draw lines and for a line at least 2 xy pairs are needed. To only draw a point, plot accepts a third parameter, for example 'ro' to represent a red dot. Supposing `u` is meant to be the `y` direction and you don't have an `x`, you could give it a zero:

`plt.plot(0, u, 'ro')`

Now, probably you want to draw a curve of `u` for different values of some `x`. As in your equation there is no `x` nor a `t`, it is hard for me to know what you would like to see on the horizontal direction.

Let's suppose you want to show `u` as a function of `d` and that `d` goes from `0.0` to `0.0005`. Typically, with numpy you create a [sequence of values](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) for `d`, lets say split into 200 small intervals:  `d = np.linspace(0.0, 0.0005, 200)`. Then, there is the [magick of numpy](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/VectorizedOperations.html), that when you write `u = f(d)`, numpy makes an array for `u` with as many entries as `d`.

Example:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n = 0.4
k = 53
d = np.linspace(0.0, 0.0005, 200)  # 0.000264
r = 0.000132
p = 15000
u = (n / n + 1) * (p * 1 / 2 * k) ** (1 / n) * (d ** ((n + 1) / n) - r ** ((n + 1) / n))
plt.plot(d, u)
plt.show()
```

[image: the plot]